# Write a subspace as a Kernel of a linear application

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations, direct-sum

I'd like to discuss the following problem :

Write U = { $f \in V | \hspace{0.3 cm}x^{2} | f$},where | means "divides", and $ V = \mathbb{R}_{k}[x]$

As kernel of the linear application : $$ F : \mathbb{R}_{k}[x] \longmapsto \mathbb{R}^{s}$$

With k that doens't depend on s,

And write down the matrix of change basis in the canonical basis of $\mathbb{R}_{k}[x]$ and $\mathbb{R}^{s}$.

The second part should be quite easier once found what $F$ does.

My attempt was to pass in coordinates because the kernel of $ F : \mathbb{R}_{k}[x] \longmapsto \mathbb{R}^{s}$ should be equal to the kernel of $ \phi : \mathbb{R}^{k+1} \longmapsto \mathbb{R}^{s}$,

Trying to find $U$ in $\mathbb{R}^{k+1}$ writing $$\mathbb{R}^{k+1} = Span \begin{pmatrix}a \\ b \\ c+1 \\ \cdots \\ k \end{pmatrix} \bigoplus Span \{e_{1}, \cdots e_{s} \}$$ with $e_{3}$ missing, and $\{a,b,\cdots,k\} \in \mathbb{R}$,

And defining $\phi$ to be zero on the vectors of $Span \begin{pmatrix}a \\ b \\ c+1 \\ \cdots \\ k \end{pmatrix}$,

This will work ?

Any help would be appreciated, thank you all!

Comment: Looks rather weird. What is ${\Bbb R}_k[x]$? First study the structure of $U$.

Comment: @Wuestenfux U should be the ideal generated by $x^{2}$ ?

Comment: What about $F\colon p(x)=p_0+p_1x+\ldots\mapsto (p_0,p_1)$?

Answer (score 1):

Observe that $U$ consists of all polynomials of the form $f(x)=a_kx^k+a_{k-1}x^{k-1}+...+a_2x^2$.

Now let $s=2$ and define $F : \mathbb{R}_{k}[x] \longmapsto \mathbb{R}^{2}$ as follows:

If $f \in V$ and $f(x)=a_kx^k+a_{k-1}x^{k-1}+...+a_2x^2+a_1x+a_0$,

then $F(f):=(a_1,a_0)$.

Show that $F$ has the desired properties.